# PHP function not displaying variables

Tags: php, function

included php file:

```
    <?php
     session_start();

     $mysqli = new mysqli('[removed]', '[removed]', '[removed]', '[removed]') or mysqli_connect_error();

     function m($str, $mysqli) { return "'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($str)."'"; }
     function h($str, $mysqli) { echo $mysqli->htmlspecialchars($str); }

     $user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

     $user_query = "SELECT points FROM users WHERE username =" .m($user, $mysqli) ."";
     $result = $mysqli->query($user_query);
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     $points = $row['points'];

     function checklogin(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo $user . " Points: " . $points; 
        }
      }
    ?>
```

the html relevant part would be

```
<? include ('config.php')
   session_start(); 
   checklogin(); ?>
```

Note: The variables work perfectly when called outside of the function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't display the variables.

Comment: Why are you trying to escape your variables twice?

Comment: Please improve your questions title. It is so no saying that it makes *naaaarrrgggh* when reading it ;) Hint: http://php.net/language.variables.scope

Comment: It does throw an notice. You just don't have error reporting (fully) enabled.

Comment: Look in your HTML source. You will probably find that the PHP code is visible. The reason for this (and the solution to part of your problem) can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this according to best practices, the following is better than using global variables.

```
    function checklogin($user,$points)
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            echo $user . ' Points: ' . $points;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking of passing parameter, but for some reason I thought it wouldn't work. I guess it goes to show that you should test everything for the sake of testing!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Thoses variables are global so you can not expect those being insde the `checkLogin` function. Therefore you pass the values as function parameters:

```
function checklogin($user, $points, $session) {

    if (!isset($session['username'])) return;

    echo $user, " Points: ",  $points; 
  }
```

Usage:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
checklogin($user, $points, $_SESSION);
```

Technically you do not need to pass `$_SESSION` as parameter, we do it in the example so that it can be replaced later on and the function does not need to have an `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: eeeew. Why make it `global` when you can pass it as argument?

Comment: Yeah, definitely shouldn't be suggesting the use of global as an actual solution...pass them in as arguments. eeeew is right.

Comment: `global` don't make them global there are global already because it's outside the function, and you need to use global to telling php, 'hey theses variables are global look it up use it'.

Comment: I know what `global` does. I'm just saying it is bad practice.

Comment: @Welling: Prefer to pass as parameters otherwise OP will come next time saying it does not work because by accident `$user` isn't global any more or changed or whatever ... parameters is just safe and sound.

Comment: @hakre true true, but im expecting he want the solutions why is not showing up, but suggestion passing as parameter work perfect as well sure it does, my bad.

Comment: Because, I mean look at the question, if *that* is a problem, what is *the next* problem? Right?

Comment: yeah i know @hakre, will struggle with more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

PHP global variables only exist at the global scope. To access them from within a function, you must carry the global scope into the function. See the following link:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong in your code:

- If you include that file you have `session_start()` twice which results in an [warning](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Qg4zRZ).
- You are trying to access variables which are not in the scope of the function, which results in an [notice](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9zsSLK).
- You are using short open tags (`<?`) which is bad practice.
- You do not have error reporting fully enabled or you would have seen the errors/notices.

Those are the things that are really wrong.

Now for some general improvements:

- give your functions better names (`m()` and `h()` suck as names, because it is not clear what they are doing). You have enough space on your harddisk, so no need to spare some letters. You will thank yourself for that if at the comming days you might not remember if it was m or h or z or p.
- look into prepared statements and bound parameters so you don't have to escape the values anymore.
- your `config.php` doesn't seem to be related to config stuff.

Some general references to help you fix these issues:

- [Variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
- [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)
- [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [Short open tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)
- [Error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
- [Display errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)